MongoDB Grouping and counting by composite field
Here's what my records look like:
I have obtained this by using collection.find().limit(1)
[
  {
    "_id": {"$oid": "..."},
    "husband.firstName": "John",
    "husband.secondName": "Smith",
    "wife.firstName": "Alice",
    "wife.secondName": "Watson",
    "...": "...",
  }
]

The husband and wife fields only contains firstName and secondName
I want to count how common each husband and wife name combos are.
I imagine the results in the form of something like:
[
  {
    "husband.firstName": "John",
    "husband.secondName": "Smith",
    "wife.firstName": "Alice",
    "wife.secondName": "Watson",
    "count": "456",
  },
  {
    "husband.firstName": "Jack",
    "husband.secondName": "Smith",
    "wife.firstName": "Alice",
    "wife.secondName": "Watson",
    "count": "123",
  }
]

I'm using Python and pymongo so I have tried the following:
pipeline = [
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": {
                "husband": "$husband",
                "wife": "$wife"
            },
            "count": {"$sum": 1}
        }
    },
    {
        "$sort": {"count": -1}
    },
]

However this returns an empty result of:
[
  {
    "_id": "{}",
    "count": 47553
  }
]

I tried also grouping by the fields separately but the result was the same.

problem is with your field format. you have . in the fields. so you actually dont have $husband or $wife fields. here for you to compare https://mongoplayground.net/p/RDHwPfEWNpW and https://mongoplayground.net/p/0uyZnMcymNc

if your data is like that where dots in fieldname you should  change it since it is not recommended

if you have no real choice you might have to use helpers such as getField https://mongoplayground.net/p/ABFRPQ4_S7A  . https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/dot-dollar-considerations/

As pointed out in the comments by @cmgchess, the main difficulty for your case is the dot in your field name. You may want to refactor your schema to something like below:
{
    "husband": {
      "firstName": "John",
      "secondName": "Smith"
    },
    "wife": {
      "firstName": "Alice",
      "secondName": "Watson"
    }
  }


Nevertheless, for your current schema, you may workaround it through usage of $getField.
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": {
        "husband": {
          "firstName": {
            "$getField": {
              "field": "husband.firstName",
              "input": "$$ROOT"
            }
          },
          "secondName": {
            "$getField": {
              "field": "husband.secondName",
              "input": "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        },
        "wife": {
          "firstName": {
            "$getField": {
              "field": "wife.firstName",
              "input": "$$ROOT"
            }
          },
          "secondName": {
            "$getField": {
              "field": "wife.secondName",
              "input": "$$ROOT"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "count": {
        "$sum": 1
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "count": -1
    }
  }
])

Mongo Playground

can even shorten the getField a bit https://mongoplayground.net/p/ABFRPQ4_S7A
